# How do I find the first struct where a particular member has a specific value?

Tags: matlab, struct, find

## Background

I have a data vector, called STRUCT_A that contains the following structs.  Each of these structs have sub values that are populated from a Jenkins build at random.  Below is an example of one instance of this data vector:

```
BEGIN STRUCT for STRUCT_A
    somemember_: 4
    anothermember_: 3
    location_: "New York"
END STRUCT for STRUCT _A

BEGIN STRUCT for STRUCT_A
    somemember_: 6
    anothermember_: 123
    location_: "South Bend"
END STRUCT for STRUCT_A

BEGIN STRUCT for STRUCT_A
   somemember_: 10
   anothermember_: 6
   location_: "Baton Rouge"
END STRUCT for STRUCT_A
```

You can access any particular member with the following syntax: `STRUCT_A.anothermember(2)` will return `123` for example.

## Problem and attempted solution

I want to find the very first struct where a `1` occurs in the `anothermember_:` member, then return the value of `somemember_` in that very same struct.  I have done some research on the [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) command, but this focuses on members of one vector. My situation deals with structs that have multiple members. Below is the closest example of what I am trying to do:

[image]

The picture above shows a 4-by-4 magic square matrix called `X`.  What I am trying to do in the example above is find the first `2` in the matrix, which in this case is located at position five. Where this 2 is located will change each time the Jenkins build is run. The example above deals with the first half of my broader issue. However, I am not sure how to translate this method into a struct, hence my question...

## Question

How do I find the first struct where a a particular member of said struct has a specific value?

Comment: Can you share some MATLAB code to reproduce? No screenshots

Comment: The format of your data is a little unclear. Do you have a vector of structure elements, or a structure storing vectors in its fields? The first would be indexed like `STRUCT_A(2).anothermember`, while the second would be indexed like `STRUCT_A.anothermember(2)`.

Comment: Another question... in your example, are you looking for a field *equal* to `1`, or a field that contains a number with `1` in it?

Comment: @gnovice The right side of the colon in the code example I give above..if that answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
% Reproduction example
a = struct('somemember_',1);
b = struct('somemember_',2);
c = struct('somemember_',2);
struct_array = [a b c];

elementOfInterest = 2;

% Find index of first occurence of element of interest in the struct array
find([struct_array.somemember_] == elementOfInterest,1)
```

returns

```
2
```